# datagridview row cell value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have search the web for an answer but have not found it. This is C# winforms.
Is is possible to do something like this:

```
private void datagridItems_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
int ID;
DataGridViewRow row = this.datagridItems.Rows[e.RowIndex];
DataGridViewCell cell = row.Cells[e.ColumnIndex];

if (row.Cells[2].Value == some value)
{
//set the value of a cell
row.Cells[4].Value = new value;
}
}
```

I need to clear existing contents of the cell[4] based on some other criteria in cell[2].

Thanks for any help.
Ryan

Comment: in which method? what is 'e'?

Comment: `e` shows you're in some event handler. Which one exactly? If you're too late in the page/control life cycle all your changes are ignored. Should be on some data bound event, possibly `DataGrid_RowDataBound`

Comment: Yes, it's possible. Have you tried the above code? What problems did you have?

Comment: and is this winforms or asp.net?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the DataGridView is databound, you shouldn't directly modify the content of the cell. Instead, you should modify the databound object. You can access that object through the DataBoundItem of the DataGridViewRow :

```
MyObject obj = (MyObject)dataGridView.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
obj.MyProperty = newValue;
```

Refresh the grid afterwards if your bound object does not support INotifyPropertyChanged events.

Comment: Makes sense. Why do I not want to modify the cell directly? I would like to understand further. Thx

Comment: Depending on the object you are binding to, the change to the cell might not make the change to your underlying object. So when you use the bounded object later in another function. What you see on the grid and what you see in the code behind can be different.

Comment: Hi Ryan.. what you mentioned is right... I'm struggling lot to make an update statement work for my windows application... problem is i'm binding the grid to the datasource in another function for pagge wise display....when I tried to update the grid its not getting updated in the backend SQL database....Is there any solution wok for this ?

Comment: Hi Gowtham, the solution i provided does not cover updating the SQL database. This is only for updating the DataGridView. If you need to update your database with the new values, you would need to write a new function for saving. Look around for some tutorials on ADO.NET or EF.